# Rename all files in a directory to a sequential default

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, batch-file, cmd.exe, mp3

I have a set of mp3 files in a subdirectory (`mayor`), and i want to convert each one using ffmpeg (like this: `ffmpeg -i <input_file> -ar 44100 -ab 128k -f mp3 <output_file>`), with the result file stored in a sibling folder `mayor_out` in a sequential pattern.
I tried with some stack's `FOR` questions, but no one explained how to do it in a file/directory iteration, so i ask a new question.

Comment: Give an example before and after of what you want the structure to go from and to look like afterwards with before and after file level examples as well. You'd typically need to show some effort for the task whether you got it to work or not (your stab at it), but a little more clarification at least may get you more help and consider updating your question with an [edit] with one of the `FOR` loop examples you have even if you don't understand or get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i managed to do this using this .bat script (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5618079/4836556))

```
@echo off
cd /D mayor
set _num=1
FOR /R %%X IN (*.mp3) DO call :body %%X
goto :eof

:body
ffmpeg -i %1 -ar 44100 -ab 128k -f mp3 ../mayor_out/YAL_m%_num%.mp3
set /a "_num=_num+1"
goto :eof
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Powershell should perform the commands you require, adjust paths as needed:

1. Create a file in the "parent" directory (E.g. C:\parent\) called "ProcessMp3.ps1" and add the code below to it.

   ```
   ForEach($i in Get-ChildItem -filter "*.mp3" -Path "C:\parent" ){  
      ffmpeg -i $i -ar 44100 -ab 128k -f mp3 ".\sibling\$i"
   }
   ```
2. Create a directory called "sibling" under the parent directory, e.g. "C:\parent\sibling\".
3. In a command prompt run:

   ```
   Powershell ./ProcessMp3.ps1
   ```

If sequential just means adding a 1,2,3, etc as a prefix to the filename then the script might look like this:

```
$c=1
ForEach($i in Get-ChildItem  -filter "*.mp3" -Path "C:\parent" ){  
  ffmpeg -i $i -ar 44100 -ab 128k -f mp3 ".\sib\$c-$i"
  $c++
}
```